# Non-harmonic-like series that diverges even though $a_\infty=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The only series that I can think of is the harmonic series or the harmonic series with primes, which are well known. Are there any other series of this type?

Comment: $a_n=\frac{3n+1}{n^2 +2}$ should satisfy your requirement.

Comment: As $n\to \infty$, $a_n =\frac{3n}{n^2}=\frac{3}{n}$

Comment: In general, series that diverge with a limit that go to 0 either go 0 slower than 1/n,  or to 0 "very slightly" faster than 1/n.   (That's a very loose term).   So you'll generally see things like 1/(something smaller than n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac1{\ln n}$

Comment: Or, perhaps more surprisingly, $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\ln n}$, which has terms which go to zero more quickly than those of the harmonic series.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y_j$ be any sequence of real numbers that does not have a finite limit as $j \to \infty$.  Let $x_j$ be an increasing sequence of positive integers that grows so rapidly that $x_{j+1} - x_{j} > j |y_{j+1} - y_{j}|$.  For $x_j \le n < x_{j+1}$ take
$a_n = (y_{j+1} - y_j)/(x_{j+1} - x_j)$.  Then $|a_n| < 1/j \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and $\sum_{x_1}^{x_M} a_n = y_M - y_1$ has no limit as $M \to \infty$.